# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myproject.DLL but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, mobile-website

What does this error mean?, I keep getting this error, it use to work fine and it just started throwing this error.... any help?

```
img1.ImageUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Url").Replace("###", randomString) 
 + Server.UrlEncode(((System.Web.UI.MobileControls.Form)Page.FindControl("mobileForm")).Title);
```

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   MyProject.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means somewhere in your chain of calls, you tried to access a Property or call a method on an object that was `null`.

Given your statement:

```
img1.ImageUrl = ConfigurationManager
                    .AppSettings
                    .Get("Url")
                    .Replace("###", randomString) 
                + Server.UrlEncode(
                      ((System.Web.UI.MobileControls.Form)Page
                      .FindControl("mobileForm"))
                      .Title);
```

I'm guessing either the call to `AppSettings.Get("Url")` is returning null because the value isn't found or the call to `Page.FindControl("mobileForm")` is returning null because the control isn't found.

You could easily break this out into multiple statements to solve the problem:

```
var configUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Url");
var mobileFormControl = Page.FindControl("mobileForm")
                            as System.Web.UI.MobileControls.Form;

if(configUrl != null && mobileFormControl != null)
{
    img1.ImageUrl = configUrl.Replace("###", randomString) + mobileControl.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a null reference somewhere in there. Can you debug the app and stop the debugger when it gets here and investigate? Probably `img1` is null or `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Url")` is returning null.

Comment: yes i see that `is null` but it was working all fine before.. how would you handle the "is null"